# Flex 3 - sporadic erroneous mouse out events on slider thumb

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mouseevent, sliders

The slider thumbs in my Flex 3 application usually work correctly, but often they seem to become insensitive to mouse downs on what should be thumbPress events.

It turns out that mouseOut events are being fired as the mouse moves away from the edge of the thumb towards the center. The thumb is sensitive to mouseDown events only when it is in the "over" state.

I am seeing the same behavior:
-- Displaying the default thumb rather than my custom class
-- Using a hitArea sprite (I tried a child TextInput sized to cover the thumb with alpha 0).

Can anyone suggest either a fix or a workaround? I can identify the faulty mouse out events, but then don't know how to compensate, for example, by reestablishing the "over" state, or perhaps with programmatic control of the mouse.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured this out myself. The mouse-out events are due to mostly invisible objects in the way -- the result of a workaround from long ago that I forgot about! :-(